# play random music but without repeating and at the end of the song start next

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am writing to ask you, I have my code that plays songs randomly when you press a button, but how can I make the songs not repeat themselves and when one ends, the next starts?

```
def play_music():

        songs = ("sonidos/playlist/cant toch this.mp3", 
        "sonidos/playlist/hey song.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/i like to move it.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/lets go.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/little bit.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/ohohoho.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/pump it up.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/pump up the jum.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/seven nation army.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/ready for this.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/seven nation army.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/usher yeah.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/what is love.mp3")
        
        selected_song = random.choice(songs)   
        pygame.mixer.music.load(selected_song) 
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: You need to store the last value of `selected_song` and keep choosing until the next choice is different.

Comment: Just use `random.shuffle()` to randomize the song list and then play the songs in the list one by one.

Comment: thanks, i will do, and so that when one ends, the other starts?

Comment: @arthurramirez No it just randomize the song list, you need to add code to play the list one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle()` to randomize the song list and play the songs in the randomized list one by one.

Below is the modified `play_music()`:

```py
def play_music():
    # songs need to be a list instead of tuple if random.shuffle() is used
    songs = [
        "sonidos/playlist/cant toch this.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/hey song.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/i like to move it.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/lets go.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/little bit.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/ohohoho.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/pump it up.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/pump up the jum.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/seven nation army.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/ready for this.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/seven nation army.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/usher yeah.mp3",
        "sonidos/playlist/what is love.mp3"
    ]

    # randomize the song list
    random.shuffle(songs)
    # play the songs in the list one by one
    for song in songs:
        print(f"playing '{song}' ...")
        pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        # wait until the song completes
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pass
```

Note that a simple for loop is used to play the songs one by one.  If you want to integrate into tkinter application, you may need to use other logic.

Comment: It works perfectly with lists, but the application crashes when it is executed, could it be that the loop is wrong?

Comment: @arthurramirez What do you mean by *"application crashes"*? If it is freezing issue on tkinter, I have already said in my answer that you need to find another way to integrate into it.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking but it seems to be a problem with the library, it works perfectly but the application freezes and I can't press other buttons